# Is it a passive tense or a 'Subject + linking verb +predicative' pattern?

Tags: passive-voice

This caused the construction of gigantic buildings **where too large masses of human beings are *crowded* together**

In the attributive clause after 'where' above, is '***crowded***' **the past participal** of the action verb '**crowd**' (i.e., a passive tense) or is it **an adjective** to describe the state of human beings?

I tend to think it is a passive tense to stress the action as people do not have any active roles in the context of the article (i.e., the impact of industralizaiton on our society).

Comment: It depends on how you interpret it. It could be either. But since it comes after *are*, it's more likely (although not certainly) used in an adjectival rather than verbal sense.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jason. Does the word **together** at the end of the sentence allude to  a kind of manner for the action **crowd**?

Comment: *Crowded together* is both a kind of idiom and a form of redundancy. If the people are *crowded* it doesn't make sense that they could be anything other than *crowded together*. However, we normally use the two words as a phrase despite that. But *together* will pair with both the adjectival and verbal sense of *crowded*. So, it's not that word that determines the difference.

Comment: Got you, Jason. If you were an English teacher, how would you explain this sentence to a student gramatically?

Comment: I would simply say, "By using that sentence, are you describing the *current state* of the crowd (in which case *crowded* is being used adjectivally) or the action that was taken?" Another way of looking at it is this: "If you add ***now*** in front of *crowded* does it change what you want to express?" If it *does*, then you'd meant *crowded* to be taken as a verb.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense, adding a temporal tag definitely make it a passive tense.